# Unable to return custom object when using Python's Pool map method

Tags: python, python-2.6, pool, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to write a simple test program in python using multiprocessing. I am using Pool.map() . To it, I am passing the method which should be invoked by the child process.
It works correctly and I get the expected result when return type is python built-in type eg string, datetime etc.
However when I use my custom class as a return type, my process just hangs. Not sure if I am doing the right thing, any suggestions would be highly appreciated. here is my code below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult
import time
import os
import logging
import multiprocessing
import sys


class C( object ):

    def __init__(self, a, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b        


    def f(self, name):            
        time.sleep(2) 

        #Doing some processing using custom classes 
        #and generating a result of custom type

        x = someMethodInCustomClass()

        # x now has list of list of custom objects eg x =[[c1,c2],[c3,c4]]

        return x                 
        #Above doesn't work. Returning string/datetime instead of x works fine.                   

    def _run(self):
        print 'Reached inside run..'
        print 'main process id ..', os.getpid()
        pool = Pool(processes=6)
        names = ['frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas', 'jim', 'rock', 'stonecold', 'machoman']        
        result = pool.map(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(names), names), 1)         
        print type(result)
        print result


    def hello(self):
        print 'Running hello....'
        self._run()

def test():
    logger.info( 'Starting....test')
    c = C(1, 2)
    print 'Running test....'
    c.hello()    

def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    print 'inside unwrap_self_f'
    return C.f(*arg, **kwarg)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Loading multiprocessing...'
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  
    test()
```

I am using Python 2.6.6. OS is windows-32bit/64 bit.

Comment: You're not returning the class, you're returning a call to an instance method within the class: `return C.f(*arg, **kwarg)`

Answer (score 0):

[pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) returns an `iterable` which has no `wait` method.

```
    result = pool.map(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(names), names), 1)
    result.wait() # <---  no such thing
```

There is no need to wait because "It blocks until the result is ready.".

Comment: You are right here..the wait()method shouldnt have been there..I was trying to use map_async() as well, it is leftover from that.

Comment: So what did you end up using? The code without "wait" is working for me... If this is the answer to your question, please accept it. If not - change the question or explain what is wrong.

Comment: The code (without the wait()) works fine..But in the f(), I am returning a string. If I try to return a list of list of custom objects..it doesn't work..the program never returns..see the updated f(). That is what I am trying to achieve. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you try and re-create the problem? It's hard to know what isn't working without reproducing it locally. The method you're referencing to demonstrate your problem does not exist.

Comment: Think of "someMethodInCustomClass()" as some method of a class in a custom module which I am importing. This method returns list of list of objects of custom type. I am trying to return this value. 
Now when I run my script, it doesnt finish execution, it keeps on running indefinitely. It seems to stuck at line:
result = pool.map(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(names), names), 1)
It doesn't print type of result and result.
In the meantime, I will see if I can recreate the problem.